# How to create this view(at most 4 images in a page then swipe rest as same)?

Tags: android

Let's say I have dynamic number of items coming from server. I can only show 4 items at most in one page. Other pages whould be accesible with swipe Please have a look at the image below. What is the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Use `Gridlayout` for Item  With `ViewPager `for pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved using

- View pager
- Pager Indicator
- A fragment with four view (Use proportionate layout)  or use grid
  view

**Approach**

- The decision on number of pages will lie on the data received from
  server.

For example:
if number of item recieved is 17
the number of pages will be 17/4+ 1(only if 17%4>0)

- pass the page index to the fragment along with the complete list.

For example if page index in view pager 4

Make sure to keep the check ( index+4<=size of list of item) 
if (index+4>size of list of item) then the the item to be displayed will start from index and will go on till the size of list.
if(index+4<=size of list)the item to be displayed will start from index i.e 4 in this case till next four element in list of items provided to the fragment.

In this way you can always get the required item out of the complete list